# checking for null in javascript

Tags: javascript, null, conditional-operator

```
if (valid === null) {
  return '';
} else if (!valid) {
  return 'is-not-valid';
} else if (valid) {
  return 'is-valid';
} else {
  return '';
}
```

I have the above if-else-if chain in the code, trying to see if I can write the same logic in one or two lines.

Comment: The `else` statement will never be hit so you can remove that already.

Comment: why not simply `!!valid` or `Boolean(valid)` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to distinguish between three types of values, you have to make at least two checks already. The `else` case will never be hit since either `!valid` or `valid` will be `true`. That also means you can reduce the last `else if` to an `else`:

```
if (valid === null) {
  return '';
} else if (!valid) {
  return 'is-not-valid';
} else {
  return 'is-valid';
}
```

But you could condense this logic using the [*conditional operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
return valid === null ? '' : (valid ? 'is-valid' : 'is-not-valid');
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I think your example (sans the redundant else block) looks pretty good, you can write it on one line like this:

```
return valid === null ? '' : (valid ? 'is-valid' : 'is-not-valid')
```

I prefer the original though